# Practical example of laying out a view at the center of the window and above other views

Tags: view, z-index, react-native

I searched and found that z-ordering of views is done by setting position of the style as 'absolute', and then specifying top, bottom, left, and right of the view.

However, in this situation, to ensure the view is right at the center, we have to first measure the width and height of the view, and do some subtraction and addition to find the absolute left and top corner of the view, like this:

```
<View style={{position: 'absolute', left: {deviceWidth / 2 - self.width / 2}, top: {deviceHeight / 2 - self.height / 2}}} />
```

which is not preferred obviously.

Anyone has a practical solution to laying out views (eg. progress bar) at the center of the window, while being above other views?

Answer (score 0):

Views are laid out top to bottom so that those on the bottom (in code) are elevated above the others (in the view)